# java compiling error when object creation

Tags: java, java-8

I'm struggling with running a java code.I have two classes in a same folder they are Ayo.java and Byo.java but when compiling Byo.java there is an error "cannot find symbol class Ayo".But the same code is working in other computers.I checked for environmental variables , they had set correctly and i'm using jdk 1.8.0_65.

```
 class Ayo{
     String  abcd(){
     return "hii";
     }
 }



public class Byo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Ayo a=new Ayo();
        System.out.println(a.abcd());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling from command line or using IDE? Try to compile with `javac -cp . Byo.java`.

Comment: @TagirValeev by command line, using javac -cp . Byo.java compiled successfully  but when running error saying that "Could not load or find main class "

Answer (score 0):

The problem was override class path had over ridden in environment variables

Answer (score -3):

Use `javac *.java` to compile the source code & `java -cp . Byo` to run

Comment: You don't need to import classes in current package.

Comment: @TagirValeev after removing the import also not working

Comment: @Raju Did you compile `Ayo.java` before compiling `Byo.java`. Or use `javac *.java` to compile both the files at the same time, compiler will compile `Ayo.java` before compiling `Byo.java`

Comment: @uthavaakkarai yhh i tried when using javac *.java there are no compile errors but when running error saying that : Could not load or find main class Byo

Comment: @Raju When running, you should mention the classpath, `java -cp . Byo` should work

Comment: @uthavaakkarai Thank you it's working ..The problem was i override class path in environment variable